# MS-Access - Easiest way to automatically extract a table

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

Here's the background for my question:

My program will be getting a new copy of an MS-Access database every night, and I need way to automatically pull data from one table of out it. (Preferably using Python).

I don't know much about Access but so far I'm thinking I could save the file on a windows computer, (launch it?) and access the data via ODBC.  Would that work, is  there an easier way?  How would I automatically launch it and start ODBC running?

I'm open to other suggestions, for example is there a way to parse the Access file directly?  Or run an export script from within Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read data in Access using ODBC without opening it.  You just need to know the file location, and the [connection string](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007).  Then read data from your table using SQL commands.